# login in codeigniter, how compare passwords

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I try to write a login using this tutorial http://www.iluv2code.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html but i have a problem with validate password. My database look identical and when i try login all time i have 
`'Invalid username or password'`
but if i do `if(1)` rather `if($result)` in `VerifyLogin.php` is ok so i think problem is in query of validation. anybody know how improve that? or how get only password from this database? i try to compare manualy...

MODEL:

```
function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->database();
}

function login($username, $password)
{
   $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
   $this -> db -> from('users');
   $this -> db -> where('username', $username);
   $this -> db -> where('password', MD5($password));
   $this -> db -> limit(1);


   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
   {
     return $query->result();  //row

   }
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Here is example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147987/can-someone-tell-me-why-my-verify-password-is-not-working-in-codeigniter

Comment: unrelated I know but please DON'T use MD5 to hash your passwords in this way. It is very insecure, I would reccommend using `hash('sha512', $password)`. Any hackers that manage to get a copy of your database would easily be able to convert these back into your users passwords.

Comment: where is your controller code??

Comment: i try paste but stack doesn't allowed me ;/

Comment: all time result from login = 0 ;/

Answer (score 0):

```
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->users->checkloginauth($username, $password);        

        if(isset($result) && count($result) > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', $result[0]['id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('firstname', $result[0]['firstname']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lastname', $result[0]['lastname']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('email', $result[0]['email']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('status', '1');

            redirect(site_url('home'), 'refresh');

            exit;
         }
         else
         {
            $data['errormsg'] = "Invalid UserName or password.";
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
         }
```

if you use md5 then write $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));

In users model

```
public function checkloginauth($username, $password)
{

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($this->users." AS u");

    $this->db->where('u.username', $username);
    $this->db->where('u.password', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    return $result->result_array();
}
```

result_array() return value in array so data are store in $result[0]

Comment: don't encourage the use of MD5 ;)

Comment: for set_userdata you create new table?

Answer (score 0):

use isset

```
if(isset($query))
{
   return $query->result();  //row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can not allow the Usename and password should not be like charectres and number also..if the same only then get results

```
public function checkloginauth($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from($this->users." AS u");

    $this->db->where('u.username LIKE BINARY', $username);
    $this->db->where('u.password LIKE BINARY', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    return $result->result_array();
}
```